# Why my multiprocessing could pause for a while?

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, multiprocessing, iot, influxdb

I'm doing my iot work by using raspberry pi and influxdb.

I want to collect data and write to influxdb. My pi is 4B, Influxdb version is 1.8.Using python script.
By Chronograf, I find that there are breakpoints in the data I write in.

Like this，the sudden polyline is the breakpoints.
[image: The begin of breakpoints]
[image: the end of breakpoints]

I use multiprocessing with producer and consumer method.

Producers collect the data, write it in JS format, and put it in queues.

Consumer make a list and append the queue's data. Send to influxdb when the list's length is 10000.

I have checked by using logging.info, and find the producer will pause for a while so there will be breakpoints. But I do not know why this could happened?

Here is the related code:

```
def producer(q):
    while True:
        timeNow=datetime.utcnow()  
        adc = spi.transfer(device_0, data_out)
        val = (adc[1]*256 + adc[2]-412)/512  #read data
        js = {
                "measurement": "mydb",
                "time": timeNow,
                "tags": {
                },
                "fields": {
                    "sensor": val
                }
        }
        q.put(js) #put in queue

def consumer(q):
    body=[]
    i=0
    while True:
        while i<10000:
            body.append(q.get()) #get js from queue
            i+=1
        i=0
        res = client.write_points(body) #send data
        body.clear()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    q=Queue(maxsize = 10000000) #set queue length
    device_0 =  spi.openSPI(device="/dev/spidev0.0",
                            mode=0,
                            speed=1000000) #set spi sampling rate 1000000
    data_out = (1,128,0)
    adc=(0,0,0) 
    client = InfluxDBClient(host='localhost', port=8086, username='admin', password='admin', database= 'mydb',ssl=False, verify_ssl=False) #set influxDB
    p1 = Process(target=producer,args=(q,))
    c1 = Process(target=consumer,args=(q,))
    p1.start()  
    c1.start()
```

The data volume is about 10k per second. I know my program is rudimentary. I'm new to coding.。

How could my program improve? How do I solve the breakpoint problem?

I will appreciate for any useful advice.

Thanks!

Comment: Linux isn’t a realtime OS. How long are the delays? How often do they happen? Have you tried a simple program which isn’t receiving data which tries to write something to DB every 100us and seen how regularly the output is produced?

Comment: The delay could be about 0.05s or more. It happened when the consumer()'s new loop start. I have tried just send data every 100us, the breakpoint will appear, too. How to solve that?

Comment: I expect it’s simply a feature of Pi Linux and probably every other linux flavour: they aren’t real-time OS and you will get unpredictable time delays due to kernel, swapping, other higher-priorty tasks, etc. Same thing probably happens on Windows. This is the reason you might use an “embedded” non-Linux environment: to get more predictable response times. Maybe you could devolve the responsibility for making the 10kHz readings to a separate e.g. arduino (i.e. not Linux-based, and carefully programmed) with enough buffering to then be able to send data to Pi without losing anything

Comment: You might want to try using DMA with SPI - not sure this is possible but if it is you can maybe assure the I/O aspect of this keeps going regardless of the Linux process switching etc. That’s going on.

Comment: Yeah, I run this script on windows, the problem will also appear. You mean this may be the problem of system, but not my code's logic or using python ? BTW, could you give some reference about they aren't real time OS? Thanks !

Comment: Your test shows there’s not a problem with just collecting the readings. It’s a well-known fact that Linux and Windows aren’t realtime - do some goggling. There’s a version of linux called rtlinux, and there are ‘preemptive’ linux kernels which apparently improve Linux’s realtime performance, so you need to do some research. Also check out DMA with SPI, that might be able to improve your application’s performance.

Comment: I looked up some documents and found that the raspberry pi's spi  has DMA by default. So It may be the kernel's problem?

Comment: I'm not sure there is a "problem" in the sense of a "bug" - it's quite likely this is just the way Linux works on a Pi. Yes it's a problem for you wanting to get fastish realtime work done, but Linux was never intended to offer that sort of capability.